# How to take template mixin as argument?

Tags: c++, templates, mixins

Considering a C++ template mixin structure, how can I write a function that takes a mixin with a specific component? In this example, how can I give `withAandB` to `worksWithA()`?

```
struct Base {};

template <class T>
struct HasA : T
{
    int A;
};

template <class T>
struct HasB : T
{
    int B;
};

void WorksWithA(HasA<Base> &p)
{
    p.A++;
}

void WorksWithAandB(HasA<HasB<Base> > &p)
{
    p.A++;
    p.B++;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HasA<Base> withA;
    HasA<HasB<Base> > withAandB;

    WorksWithA(withA); // OK
    WorksWithAandB(withAandB); // OK
    WorksWithA(withAandB); // KO, no conversion available

    return 0;
}
```

Even putting aside the construction problem, or mixin ordering (`HasA<HasB<Base>>` vs `HasB<HasA<Base>>`), I can't see a good way to write this function, beside making it a template too.

I'm currently in an environment without C++11, but I'd be interested if modern C++ provides a solution to this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can make the `WorksWithA` a template function which accepts any class wrapped with `HasA`:

```
template<typename T>
void WorksWithA(HasA<T> &p)
{
  p.A++;
}
```

In this case your code compiles with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to make your functions template as well?

```
template <class T>
void WorksWithA(HasA<T> &p)
{
    p.A++;
}

template <class T>
void WorksWithAandB(HasA<HasB<T> > &p)
{
    p.A++;
    p.B++;
}
```

Since `HasA<HasB<Base>>` is no way convertible to `HasA<Base>`.

Comment: Ok thank you! I hoped that since `HasB<Base>` derived from `Base`, there would be a way to do the conversion from `HasA<HasB<Base>>` to `HasA<Base>`

Comment: Hey I have to correct my answer, since it's like you said, `HasB<Base>` derived from `Base` so it's convertible, but `HasA<HasB<Base>>` is truly no way convertible to `HasA<Base>`, since these 2 types have no relationship. All instantiated template types are distinct, you can see them like HasA<X> and HasA<Y>, although X and Y has relationship, HasA<X> and Has<Y> are totally different.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, these functions are probably better off as templates. However, while you're at it, you can also remove some code duplication:

```
template<class B> 
void WorksWithA(HasA<B> &p) 
{ 
    p.A++; 
} 

template<class B> 
void WorksWithB(HasA<B> &p) 
{ 
    p.B++;
}

template<class Has>
void WorksWithAandB(Has &p)
{
    WorksWithA(p);
    WorksWithB(p);
}
```

Here `WorksWithAAndB` calls the other types. Hence:

1. You're reusing the code.
2. You're reusing the compiler's checks of type types passed to `WorksWithA` and `WorksWithB` for the type passed to `WorksWithAAndB`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `WorksWithA` a function template; there is no other way. Think about it: `WorksWithA` works with *any* type which has the `HasA` mixin. That can only be expressed with templates.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in the case `HasA` and `HasB` have the meaning of interfaces, consider using inheritance to solve this problem:

```
struct HasA
{
  int A;
  virtual ~HasA() = default;
};

struct HasB
{
  int B;
  virtual ~HasB() = default;
};

struct HasAB : HasA, HasB
{
};

struct Base : HasAB
{};

void WorksWithA(HasA &p)
{
  p.A++;
}

void WorksWithAandB(HasAB &p)
{
  p.A++;
  p.B++;
}
```

Here you can call `WorkWithA` with object of any class implementing the `WithA` interface, and `WorksWithAandB` with object of any class implementing `HasAB` interface.

PS: Unfortunately, in this example, it's impossible to call `WorksWithAandB` with object of class implementing both `HasA` and `HasB` without inheritance from `HasAB`, but this may be solved using templates and SFINAE.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually my current design, and I'm looking for a better way to have this "HaveAB". I'll look into the SFINAE concept.